# Special character in odata GET call using Olingo Client

Tags: java, odata, olingo, odata-v4

I am using Olingo 4.2 java library to call my OData services. I am making and odata GET call and have a special character in my parameter like www.example.com/service/People('abc}def{ghi').When i encode and make an OData call using Olingo client, I get an error--

> Geographyis not an instantiable type. An entity can declare a property to be of type Geometry. An instance of an entity MUST NOT have a value of type Geometry. Each value MUST be of some subtype.

It works fine when I execute it from browser.
I cannot avoid having {}(curly brackets) in the primary key. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What is the Olingo client you refer to? So it fails for the client but works in a standard web browser?

Comment: Olingo client is the java library I mentioned in the first line(Olingo 4.2). Yes it fails for the client but works for standard browser.

Comment: This is not clear. Olingo is a framework for implementing OData inside a Java project, it's not a client. It can also be version 2 or version 4 but it won't be version 4.2. I'm being picky, but I don't understand if it's not clear. :)